# How to get XML Elements from XmlDocument object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xmldocument

Assume that an XmlDocument is successfully loaded with this code:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(stream);
```

This is a sample portion of the XML stream (the complete XML stream has about 10000 of ProductTable's):

```
<ProductTable>
<ProductName>Chair</ProductName>
<Price>29.5</Price>
</ProductTable>
```

Using Linq, how do I access the ProductName and Price elements? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest using an `XDocument` instead of an `XmlDocument` (the latter is not suited for LINQ to XML). Use the `XDocument.Load(...)` method to load your "real" XML.

```
string xml = @"<ProductTable>
<ProductName>Chair</ProductName>
<Price>29.5</Price>
</ProductTable>";
XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var tables = x.Descendants("ProductTable");
Dictionary<string,string> products = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var productTable in tables)
{
    string name = productTable.Element("ProductName").Value;
    string price = productTable.Element("Price").Value;
    products.Add(name, price);
}
```

If you'd prefer to use sugar-coated SQL like syntax or would like to read up on the topic, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) is a great place to start.

The following is a more concise version if you feel like using an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml)
var products = /* products is an IEnumerable<AnonymousType> */
    from item in document.Descendants("ProductTable")
    select new
    {
        Name = item.Element("ProductName").Value,
        Price = item.Element("Price").Value
    };
```

You could then use this expressive syntax to print the matches in the console:

```
foreach (var product in products) /* var because product is an anonymous type */
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", product.Name, product.Price);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, codesparkle. I am going to try it later tonight when I get home. I am visiting family on Dec 25 so can only read your answer without being able to test.

Comment: codesparkle: You are an absolute genius! Your code works perfectly. Thanks so much!!!